# Why do I have an infinite useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am calling `setState` within `useEffect` and it's triggering infinitely. I'm having a hard time understanding why. The problem is with the third `useEffect` that is dependent on `picked`.

```
import GameCSS from './game.module.css'
import Dog from "./dog/dog"
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function Game () {
  const [dogs, setDogs] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [picked, setPicked] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [fave, setFave] = useState<string>('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/10')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setDogs(data.message));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setImages([dogs[0], dogs[1]]);
  }, [dogs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setImages([dogs[1], dogs[2]]);
  }), [picked];

  if (images) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={GameCSS.dogs}>
          <Dog
            image={images[0]}
            setFave={setFave}
            picked={picked}
            setPicked={setPicked}
          />
          <Dog
            image={images[1]}
            setFave={setFave}
            picked={picked}
            setPicked={setPicked}
          />
        </div>  
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Game
```

```
import DogCSS from './dog.module.css'

interface info {
  image: string;
  setFave: (image: string) => void;
  picked: boolean;
  setPicked: (toggle: boolean) => void
}

function Dog (props:info) {
  function setFave() {
    props.setFave(props.image);
    props.setPicked(!props.picked);
  }
    
  return (
    <img
      className={DogCSS.image}
      src={props.image}
      onClick={setFave}
    >
    </img>   
  )
}

export default Dog
```

> **Warning Message:** game.tsx:23 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside
> useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or
> one of the dependencies changes on every render.
> at Game (http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/components/game/game.tsx?t=1689969940032:23:27)
> at div
> at App

What is supposed to happen is that when the user clicks on an image it toggles the `picked` state and triggers the `images` to update.

I tried removing `picked` dependency from the offending `useEffect` and that did not solve it. I tried doing something other than `setImages` and that fixes it, but what I need to do is update the `images` array when the `picked` flag is toggled so I need to find a way or redesign my solution. I tried to figure out how to set the offending `useEffect` to not run on the first render, but I became a bit overwhelmed and didn't understand.

Comment: Actually in both `useEffect` calls your dependencies don't make sense - just remove them b/c the callback doesn't depend on its values. Additionally, both `useEffect` calls don't make sense - just set the desired value in the initial states.

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. It doesn't work to set the initial values. I tried it, there's nothing to load from dogs array yet. I was seeking to have images load from an API that delivers an array of urls, so I couldn't set the initial state until the API has returned the data. The other useEffect is not implemented as it would be ultimately. The images need to update when the user clicks on one (pick). Since I'm a beginner and this is just for learning, I think I'm going to change my scope to simplify things. The idea I had is harder to implement than I anticipated.

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbos](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-do-i-have-an-infinite-useeffect-9mtmtr) and see no render looping issue. Can you [edit] to clarify in better details what the issue is your app has and clear reproduction steps to cause the issue? Feel free to fork the sandbox to add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue that we could then inspect live.

Comment: @Steve I've correct myself at one point: the first `useEffect` call is alright, but still - you could just move the logic right into your `fetch` logic and call `setImages` there. The second `useEffect` doesn't make sense and has a wrong dependency. Plus, you could call `setImages` just in the click handler.

Comment: @Steve, I just ran you code locally and it doesn't have any infinite render issues. the below code however have a syntax issue -
useEffect(() => {
    setImages([dogs[1], dogs[2]]);
  }), [picked];
it should be - 
useEffect(() => {
    setImages([dogs[1], dogs[2]]);
  }, [picked]);
see if this is the actual problem you were having.

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew, I set something up on codesandbox by linking my github project, but then I realized Obydul's comment fixed my issue. Simply a misplaced bracket. I'll keep codesandbox in mind for the future. I'll probably make more posts in the future because this has been really helpful.

Comment: @ObydulIslamKhan This fixed it! Thank you. I'm surprised a syntax error led to that behavior.

Comment: @NotX I see what you are saying now. It makes a lot more sense that way. Surprisingly my infinite useEffect was caused by a misplaced bracket as pointed out in another comment. I definitely will change my design still though.

Comment: I see, glad you have it sorted out. I must've corrected the syntax issue and neglected to mention it. I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: @Steve, glad to know! also please upvote the comment if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the suboptimal design, the infinite useEffect behavior is caused by a misplaced bracket as pointed out in the comments. First snippet is incorrect, second is correct. My friend pointed out that chatGPT can be good at finding these bugs and it did find it when I tried it there.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setImages([dogs[1], dogs[2]]);
}),[picked];

useEffect(() => { 
    setImages([dogs[1], dogs[2]]); 
}, [picked]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of second and third useEffect in your code you can call setImages in first useEffect where you call setDogs.
and also no need to pass all the props to  component you can just pass the image and on an onClick method to get the event.

I optimize your code below

### Game

```
    import GameCSS from './game.module.css'
import Dog from "./dog/dog"
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function Game() {
  const [dogs, setDogs] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [fave, setFave] = useState<string>('');
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(2);
  const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/10')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setDogs(data.message)
        setImages(data.message.slice(0,2));
      });
  }, []);

  const onPressDog = (image: any) => {
    setFave(image);
    setImages(dogs.slice(count, count + 2));
    setCount(count+2)
  }
  if (images) {
    return (
      <div className={GameCSS.dogs}>
        {
          images.map(image => <Dog
            image={image}
            onPress={() => onPressDog(image)}
          />
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
  return null;
}

export default Game
```

### Dog

```
import DogCSS from './dog.module.css'

interface info {
  image: string;
  onPress: () => void;
}

function Dog(props: info) {
  return (
    <img
      className={DogCSS.image}
      src={props.image}
      onClick={props.onPress}
    >
    </img>
  )
}

export default Dog
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this. Thank you Nazir!